# Different OnClickListener for the same Firebase adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to reuse firebase adapter in two activities with different onClick Listener behaviors depending on both activities.

Here is the code:

```
        public class ProductListAdapter  {

private Query mQuery;
private Context mContext;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product,ProductViewHolder> mAdapter;
public ProductListAdapter(Query query,Context context) {

    mQuery = query;
    mContext = context;

    Update();
}



public void Update(){
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(
            Product.class,
            R.layout.list_item_product,
            ProductViewHolder.class,
            mQuery
    ){
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder, Product model, int position) {
            viewHolder.mProductTitle.setText(model.getProductTitle());
            viewHolder.mProductDescription.setText(model.getProductDescription());
            Product product = getItem(position);
            viewHolder.bindView(product);


            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(model.getPhotoUrl())
                    .into(viewHolder.mThumbnail);


        }
    };


}

public RecyclerView.Adapter getAdapter(){
    return  mAdapter;
}

public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    Product mProduct;
    TextView mProductTitle;
    TextView mProductDescription;

    ImageView mThumbnail;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mProductTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
        mProductDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_description);
        mThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


    }


    public void bindView(Product product){
        mProduct = product;
    }
}
```

And This is the code in calling activity which calls the firebaseadapter class, The class is returning an adapter using getAdapter Method and  which is given to recycler view:

```
 ProductListAdapter productListAdapter = 
  new               ProductListAdapter(query,getActivity());
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = productListAdapter.getAdapter();

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I want to reuse firebase adapter in another activity but with different onClickListener method @Shailesh

Comment: where is the onClick() in ur code?

Comment: I have not written it yet because I want to reuse onClickListener based on activity but don't know how to do it. @Yazan

Comment: @Pheonix, create a interface for this

Comment: I don't know how can you post the code @Maddy

Comment: @Pheonix, update your adapter code first

Comment: I have updated the adapter code @Maddy

Answer (score 2):

You can set `onClickListinner()` in any element inside your `viewHolder`

Try something like that:

```
        if (condition) {
            viewHolder.mThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ... doStuff
                }
            });    
        } else {
            viewHolder.mThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ... doOtherStuff
                }
            });
        }
```

About the reuse, it is best to creat a class which extends `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, and them inside it define the method `populateViewHolder`, having this condition for each `OnClickListener`.

[As a example:](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-firebaseui-with-custom-firebaserecycleradapter-example-tutorial/)

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = RecipeAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    public RecipeAdapter(Class<Product> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<ProductViewHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref, Context context) {
        super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder, Product model, int position) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then set the adapter:

```
mAdapter = new RecipeAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(
            Product.class,
            R.layout.list_item_product,
            ProductViewHolder.class,
            mQuery,
            this
    )
```

Comment: What about using adapter in 10 activities then there will be 10 if else, Do you think it's efficient way to do the job @GuilhermeFGL